# Convert associative array to key=>value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => 55
        )

)
```

i need to convert it to

```
array( '5' => '44', '9' => '55' )
```

i tried all function of arrays from php.net but i could not figure out how to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try `foreach`?

```
$result = array();
foreach($yourarray as $entry) {
  $result[$entry['id']] = $entry['name'];
}
```